# Indexing byte array in elasticsearch using spring data elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I have a byte[] (which contains pdf, doc or other files's content), that I need to store in elasticsearch and perform a full text research on the file's content.
I did some digging and found a mapper-attachment plugin which handles this kind of attachment indexation. But the dilema here is that I didn't find a way to work with that plugin in my spring project.
when I add the attachment fieldType as follows:

```
@Field(type = FieldType.Attachment)
private byte[] fileContent;
```

I get the following error : 'No handler found for [attachment] field type'.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You need to install the mapper-attachment plugin. What version of ES are you running?

Comment: I'm running ES 2.4.0

Comment: There you go: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.4/mapper-attachments.html

Comment: I've installed it but that doesn't help me in my java project. Any idea how I may use it in my spring application ? Thanks !

Comment: The error you get seems to indicate that the plugin is not installed. What do you get when running: `curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cat/plugins` ?

Comment: % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    42  100    42    0     0   2800      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 42000Poltergeist head master s /_plugin/head/

Comment: See, no mapper-attachments

Comment: yeah you're right, when I try to install it I get the following : ERROR: Plugin [mapper-attachments] is incompatible with Elasticsearch [2.4.0]. Was designed for version [2.1.2]

Comment: Try to install using this link: https://download.elastic.co/elasticsearch/release/org/elasticsearch/plugin/mapper-attachments/2.4.6/mapper-attachments-2.4.6.zip

Comment: Thanks now the plugin is installed. I'll try and run my java app again and see if the error is still there. Thanks again !

Comment: Now I get another error :  org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: Mapping definition for [fileContent] has unsupported parameters:  [store : false], I think I should edit the mapping and set the store to true

Comment: Any feedback yet?

Comment: I've just solved the second problem! Even though I set the @Field(type = FiledType.attachment), Spring generates its own mapping for the index, and overriding the 'attachment' type I set earlier to 'String' type. I ended up writing my own mapping and Put-ting in to elasticsearch and the problem is solved.

Comment: Maybe you had created your index before installing the plugin and a string field got created instead

Comment: The thing is when I drop my index and I restart my application, and by doing save(document) method of spring repository the mapping is created and string type is automatically assigned event though I ve specified attachment as type in the @Field annotation